# Validation for multiselect using PHP

Tags: php, html, validation, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a multiple select on my code, what I need to do is to have a validation when the user click the submit button without selecting any of the given list.
Here's the sample code:

**index.php**

```
<?php
IF(isset($_POST['Rtype'])){
$RetrieveType = $_POST['Rtype'];
    IF($RetrieveType == 'date_range'){
        $start_date = new DateTime($_POST['start_date']);
        $sd = date_format($start_date,'Y-m-d');
        $p_week=array();
        $m_month=01;
        $end_date = new DateTime($_POST['end_date']);
        $end_date-> add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        $ed =date_format($end_date,'Y-m-d');
}
    ELSEIF($RetrieveType == 'weekly'){
        $p_week = $_POST['week'];
        $m_week = implode(',',$p_week);
        $m_month =$_POST['month_m'];
        $m_year =$_POST['year_m'];
        $p_lob = $_POST['lob'];
        $sc_lob=implode(',',$p_lob);
} ELSE
{
  $RetrieveType = 'date_range';
        $sd = date('Y-m-01');
        $start_date = date('Y-m-01');
        $ed = date('Y-m-d');
        $end_date = date('Y-m-d');
        $m_month=date ('m');
        $p_week=array();
        $m_year= date ('Y');
        $sc_lob='';
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<head>
<body>
 <form action="index.php" method="POST" class="form-inline">
   <label for="sel1">Week:</label>
   <select data-placeholder="<?php echo (isset($_POST['week']) ? "Week/s Currently Selected: ".implode(",",$_POST['week']) : "Select Week"); ?>" 
                        class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4" style="width:350px;" name= "week[]">   
                        <option value="1" id="empty">Week 1</option>
                        <option value="2" id="empty">Week 2</option>
                        <option value="3" id="empty">Week 3</option>
                        <option value="4" id="empty">Week 4</option>
                        <option value="5" id="empty">Week 5</option>
                        </select>
    <label for="sel1">LOB:</label>
    <select data-placeholder="<?php echo (isset($_POST['lob']) ? "LOB/s Currently Selected: ".implode(",",$_POST['lob']) : "Select LOB"); ?>" 
                        class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4" style="width:350px;" name= "lob[]"> 
                        <?php
                            $lob = array();
                            $q = "SELECT distinct LOB from roster where EmployStatus='active' and SDLead <> '' group by LOB";
                                    $params = array();
                                    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $q); 

                                    while($rowsss= sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {
                                    $lob = $rowsss['LOB'];
                                        echo "<option value='".$lob."'>".$lob."</option>";
                                    }
                            for ($i = 0; $i <= count($lob) - 1; $i++) {

                                IF($sc_lob == $lob[$i])
                                {$isSelected = 'selected';}
                                elseif(1==1)
                                {$isSelected='';}
                                echo "<option ".$isSelected." value='".$lob[$i]."'>".$lob[$i]."</option>";                      }

                            ?>
                   <input type="hidden" name="Rtype" value="weekly">
                   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" />
   </form>
```

What I wanted to achieve is when the user clicked the submit button without selecting any on the "Week" list or "LOB" list, there would be an error message that says "This field is required, select at least one.". Actually I already did this before, when I'm just using a checkbox. I placed the code below after the label tag:

**sample code:**

```
<?php
                            if(isset($_GET['err']))
                            {
                                $err = $_GET['err'];
                                if($err == 1)
                                {
                                    echo "<span class='text-danger'>* This field is required, select at least one.</span>";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "";
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo "";
                            }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
    errors = 0;
    if($_POST['nameOfSelect'] == ""){
       errors++;
    }

  if(errors == 0){
     return true;
  }else{
     return false;
}
```